# Similar and simplified examples (newbie questions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently studying about web development, I still don't know about jquery, but I've a little knowledge about javascript, html and css (basic).

I've been looking at some examples in github to improve my skills, and I've found this content;

https://github.com/stewilondanga/editables

I perfectly understand the theory, but I do not know how to put it into practice, I would like for any similar examples (simplified alternatives) and how to convert the exported code generated by javascript into a html5 table?

Any example would be appreciated! thanks for your attention!

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) There are a couple of problems with this question: 1. It's not self-contained, people can't help you unless they go to off-site links (and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future). Quote the relevant material. 2. It's far too broad for SO's Q&A format. Get stuck in, do thorough research, and give it a go; **if** you run into a specific problem, show what you've done and ask about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, jQuery does not generate code. It's a framework, you load it into a web page, and then you can use it from within Javascript code in that page.

I suggest you start by looking at the source of https://stewilondanga.github.io/editables/, if an editable tables is what you need. There are more general frameworks to do this, e.g. [Aloha](https://www.alohaeditor.org/)

To try it yourself, I'd suggest you bite the bullet equip yourself with some kind of web server, be it on a server somewhere, or on your local machine, so you can easily try out things like this, copy the sources, alter the code etc.., and quickly hit reload on your browser.

While it may seem easier to run a local server and point your browser at http://localhost/something, IMHO it also takes more tinkering to get browsers to embrace that fully. You don't need the extra grief while already learning all those new concepts. If you want to tackle this seriously, consider getting a hosting service or small VPS somewhere. If you don't know how to do that, get help for that first, but get it out of the way. It'll save you much grief.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply, I know how to start a local server, this is not a problem.
Editable tables is exactly what I need, I like this idea, my goal is to create a tool to facilitate some tasks.